# Make the org-habit agenda display further into the future

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-habit

I've started using org-mode these past few days, and I've set up a few org-habits. I'm having trouble with the consistency graph and agenda mode however. Habit `TODO`s only seem to show up for habits that are due today. How can I make the org agenda show habits further into the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the variable `org-habit-show-habits-only-for-today` to `nil`.

```
org-habit-show-habits-only-for-today is a variable defined in `org-habit.el'.

Documentation:
If non-nil, only show habits on today's agenda, and not for future days.
Note that even when shown for future days, the graph is always
relative to the current effective date.
```

Then, your habits will show up on all times they are scheduled, including repetitions. They won't show up on dates in the past where you did them.

If you want each habit to show up when it is next scheduled, but no further repetitions, set `org-agenda-repeating-timestamp-show-all` to `nil`:

```
(setq org-agenda-repeating-timestamp-show-all nil)
```

Comment: Is there a way to not show the repetitions?

Comment: You should add that you can customize `org-agenda-repeating-timestamp-show-all` to hide repetitions.